# Flac Converter Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, audio, ffmpeg, flac

Does anyone know how to convert .mp3 to .flac in Objective-C using FFmpeg for iOS? Or other solutions to convert? I want to use Google's speech recognition api and of course they only support .flac audio.

Answer (score 2):

Since you can use C in objective-C, you are in good shape to use [libflac](http://flac.sourceforge.net/developers.html).

http://flac.sourceforge.net/developers.html